# Horizontal scrolling Internal Anchor Links click with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I use jquery for horizontal scrolling with mousewheel.It is work ..

```
 $('html').mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
            this.scrollLeft += (delta * 50);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

I want horizontal scrolling Internal Anchor Links click,

I use this code :

```
   $(".prevscroll").click(function (event) {
               event.preventDefault();
               $.scrollTo(this.hash, 150, { easing: 'elasout' });
        });
```

or

```
  $(window).scrollLeft((Number($(window).scrollLeft()) + 50) + 'px');
```

or

```
 $('body').scrollLeft(50);
```

but don't scrolling !!!!

My html code

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<style>
 .content
 {
padding: 20px 20px 0;
display: block;
z-index: 1;
height: 340px;
position: relative;
}
#contentWrapper
{
position: absolute;
max-width: 100%;
min-width: 400px;
min-height: 350px;
padding: 0 20px 30px 20px;
z-index: 1;
} 
</style>


<div style="display: block;top:107px" id="contentWrapper">
  <a class="prevscroll"></a>
   <div style="margin-right: 0px;" id="content">
    //My content
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show your html code or a fiddle. Horizontal scrollbar needs width for scroll let me check your code

Comment: or which pluggin you are using show us a fiddle of your code how you using this

Comment: Thanks, i horizontal scrolling with mouse wheel but i do't scrolling with anchor links click.

Comment: take a look of this websites http://vanityclaire.com/ or http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer .

```
$(".prevscroll").click(function (event) {
            $('html, body').scrollLeft($('html, body').scrollLeft()+150);
              event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your `mousewheel` function to `body` not `html`, and `-=` not `+=`. You need to **decrease** not **increase** the value of your `scrollLeft`

```
$(function() {

    $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        var $this = $(this);

        this.scrollLeft -= (delta) * 50;
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EBPdr/1/

Comment: Thanks, mousewheel work, but anchor link click don't work.(I use += because my body is right to left )